# Javascript Modal for Web Infographic

Tags: javascript, html

I am preparing a simple javascript exercise to teach college-level students in graphic design how to make things interactive on the web.

I am new to javascript as well, and I have written a simple script that shows a modal box when you click a button. The problem is, I would have to make a new function for every single button on my page. Is there a way to have one function? Below is the code I have so far.

I have also made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4w37mkse/) but the modal isn't popping up. It works on my computer. I've also uploaded my code to [my website](http://jordankennedy.com/example).

```html
<!doctype>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 1);
    }
    #mainContent {
      width: 960px;
      height: 680px;
      margin: 80px auto 0 auto;
      background-image: url(home.png);
      border: 1px solid gray;
      border-radius: 8px;
      background-color: white;
    }
    #button1 {
      position: relative;
      top: 250px;
      left: 500px;
      width: 40px;
    }
    #closeButton {
      position: absolute;
      top: -20px;
      right: -20px;
      width: 40px;
    }
    #infoBox.one {
      position: relative;
      top: 250px;
      left: 530px;
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 300px;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    function infoBox() {
      button = document.getElementById("infoBox");
      button.style.visibility = (button.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="mainContent">
    <a href='#' onclick='infoBox()'>
      <img id="button1" src="button.png" />
    </a>

    <div id="infoBox" class="one">
      <p>Your information goes here.</p>

      <a href='#' onclick='infoBox()'>
        <img id="closeButton" src="close.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're far better off starting with javascript + jQuery. jQuery allows you to act on groups of elements by class name without jumping through a lot of hoops. jQuery makes javascript a lot easier to use, particularly for non-programmers.

Comment: @Diodeus But if OP is going to teach others maybe better understanding of the roots is essential before jumping to jQuery?

Comment: They're graphic design students, not com-sci. Getting demonstrable results is of more value than knowing bare JS.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach you can try is to make use of the fact that click events bubble up the DOM tree (event delegation). So using this idea you can bind one event handler to parent container (for example `body`) and handle all clicks from there:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.parentNode.className === 'btn-modal') {
        infoBox();
    }
}, false);
```

Note: I'm checking `parentNode`'s class because click happens on the image element, which is child of the link with `.btn-modal`. Here is the version of the generic way to handle delegated events without relying on parent nodes being what we know: **http://jsfiddle.net/4w37mkse/2/** if you are interested.

In above case I denote the buttons that we want our listener to handle with specific class:

```
<a href='#' class="btn-modal">
    <img id="button1" src="http://www.jordankennedy.com/example/button.png"/>
</a>
```

This is very naive and basic example but it demonstrates the idea.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4w37mkse/1/